# How to listen specific value in DynamoDB

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using aws DynamoDB and I Want the user to listen a value inserted on a Json value. So when this value is changed the user will trigger a function in the app.

Somebody know how to make it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to setup [DynamoDB streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html). A lambda function attached to the stream is going to analyze db changes for  related to the specific item and then perform other actions specific to your application.